# Angular - two-way binding through an ng-switch

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a directive with scope and a two-way '=' binding to a parent-scope value (yes, inside an object to avoid inheritance problems.) The directive's template in turn contains an ng-switch, which of course creates another scope. Inside the ng-switch I want to have a textarea bound to the original value. It gets initialized correctly, but when the user edits the value, the parent scope value doesn't change.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.directive('csContenteditable', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            content: "=",
            editMode: "=csContenteditable",
        },
        template: 
            "<div ng-switch='editMode'>" +
                "<div ng-switch-when='false'>{{content}}</div>" +
                "<div ng-switch-when='true'><textarea ng-model='content'/><div>" +
            "<div>"

    };
});


function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.editMode = false;
    $scope.values = {value: 'foo'}
}
```

What is the right way to do this? I can use ng-show instead of ng-switch and it works, b/c there is no extra scope but makes my DOM a lot heavier than necessary in my actual real-world case.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/LF5UL/

- Click the "edit mode" checkbox
- Note the textarea is initialized with "foo"
- Now type in the textarea.
- Note the "Current value" in the outer scope doesn't update.

Answer (score 2):

it is a `scope` issue... 
ng-if directive creates a **new scope** that why your model is not updated...

if you use primitive object like you used there child scope create new instance instead of inherite from parent scope

bind `values` instead of `values.value` which is a primitive variable and your directive scope don't shadow/hide your original object...

here is your **html**

```
<div content="values" cs-contenteditable="editMode" />
```

and here is **directive's template**

```
"<div ng-switch='editMode'>" +
   "<div ng-switch-when='false'>{{content.value}}</div>" +
   "<div ng-switch-when='true'><textarea ng-model='content.value'/><div>" +
"<div>"
```

for more information look [understanding $scope](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes)...

and here is updated [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wickY26/LF5UL/3/)...

**UPDATE**

I recommend using **complex object** instead of using **$parent** because if you use some directive in your directive which create new scope like `ng-if` break your **$parent** solution, here is example [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wickY26/LF5UL/6/)...

Comment: So, I see that works, but here's the problem I have with it. Suppose my model is: recipe: { name: "foo", flavor: "bar"}. That is json coming from the server, I don't want to do horrible transformations on it both directions. Now I want to use my directive on it to edit both fields. I need to be able to write <div content="recipe.name" cs-contenteditable="editMode"> and <div content="recipe.flavor" cs-contenteditable="editMode">. I can't write <div content="recipe" cs-contenteditable="editMode">. That's why I think $parent is a better solution.

Comment: see new comment above, forgot to tag you @wickY26

Answer (score 0):

I'll be darned, I just solved this. The answer is to use `$parent.content` instead of `content` in both cases inside the directive.

Comment: or u may use `content.value` instead of `content` http://jsfiddle.net/mobinskariya/LF5UL/1/

Comment: $parent is not a good way to do basicaly you send a primitive object and child scope create new instance

Comment: @wickY26 so this is where I'm perplexed. I thought by creating the values object in the root scope and passing values.value into the directives content attribute, I should be avoiding that problem and content in the inner scope should be pointing to values.value in the outer one. Can you help me see why that isn't true? I see that your fiddle works.