# How can I edit an item in a list without changing the whole list?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, ng-switch

I have a list of discussions that have the possibility of being flagged. Currently however when a user clicks on a flag button, the `isflagged` is triggered for all the items rather than just the item that was flagged, you would need to refresh the page to flag other discussions. How would I have it so that only the discussion that was clicked changes, not every discussion.

I have the `scope.dis` because of [scope inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22433788/angular-two-way-binding-through-an-ng-switch)

html:

```
 <li ng-repeat="discussion in Discussions">
    <div ng-if="canFlag(discussion)">
        <div ng-switch="dis.isFlagging">
            <div ng-switch-when="false"
                ng-click="flagDiscussion(discussion.id)"
            </div>
            <div ng-switch-when="true">
                Successfully flagged</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

js:

```
$scope.dis = {isFlagging: false};
$scope.flagDiscussion = function(discussionId) {
    Service.flagDiscussion(discussionId);
    $scope.dis.isFlagging = true;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$scope.dis` is common for alll `discussions`. To keep track the flagging of discussion keep map or add property into the discussion.

Something like this:

```
<div ng-switch="discussion.isFlagging">
    <div ng-switch-when="false" ng-click="flagDiscussion(discussion)" />
    <div ng-switch-when="true">Successfully flagged</div>
</div>

$scope.flagDiscussion = function(discussion) {
    Service.flagDiscussion(discussion.id);
    discussion.isFlagging = true;
};
```

Comment: Can you explain further or give an example, not quite sure what you mean , thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would keep track of this in each individual `discussion` object.  You accidentally set it so that there is only one `$scope.dis` which is why it applies to every item.  Track the `isFlagging` status on an individual basis like this:

HTML:

```
<li ng-repeat="discussion in Discussions">
<div ng-if="canFlag(discussion)">
    <div ng-switch="discussion.isFlagging">
       <div ng-switch-when="false"
            ng-click="flagDiscussion(discussion)">
        </div>
        <div ng-switch-when="true">
            Successfully flagged</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

JS:

```
$scope.flagDiscussion = function(discussion) {
    Service.flagDiscussion(discussion.id);
    discussion.isFlagging = true;
};
```